# Updating visibility of element in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have **ObservableCollection < Result >** results that is ItemSource of ListBox control.
Result class contains **bool variable** that represents visibilty of one element in ListBox item through BooleanToVisibiltyConverter. When i set ItemSource it's all ok and works fine: elements that have false are not visible, and one that have true is visible. But when i change variable from true to false, the element is not changing his visibility. What is problem?

Now i need to do this magic:

```
ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = null;
ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = results;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your class `Result` to update bindings on target element which is `ListBoxItem` in your case.

Tutorial - [How to implement property change notification.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Comment: Can you send me simple example or link, please?

Comment: Update the answer with link.